# $job->release() is not putting back on queue

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, queue, synchronization, push-queue

Very new to queues so be gentle. To my understanding, `$job->release()` is supposed to put the job back on the queue. I currently have the code below but it only runs the job through the queue once. I need to be able to run it through up to 5 times and if it fails again, delete it or something.

Worker:

```
public function fire($job, $data)
{
    if ($job->attempts() < 5) {
        \Log::error($job->attempts());
        $job->release();
    }

}
```

PUSH!:

```
 Queue::push(
     'ClassName',
      [
         'path' => $path;
      ]
```

Trying to do this locally with sync. Tried running queue:listen and queue:work, then running the push code. Only logged 1 entry. Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out `$job->release()` doesn't work when using the `sync` driver.

Comment: The `sync` driver is essentially the same as running your code synchronously, so there is no queue to release the job back to.